# Android Application Structure

Tags: android, structure, android-fragments

I'm currently working on my first ever Android application and it's for my University. The structure of this app is that there 5 specific tabs each of which when inside that tab give you multiple options to perform other actions. So for instance when you click on tab 1, you are given the option to view a news feed, twitter feed, rss feed, etc. Tab 2 might give you information about different parts of the school, so there might be a button to go to Academics Info, another button for Financial Info, etc.  I started on this about a month ago and was making good progress using ActivityGroups nested inside TabActivities. Then one day I found that both of those class had been deprecated and it was suggested that Fragments be used instead, so I restarted using Fragments. So my question is can anyone give me guidance on the overall structure behind what I'm trying to accomplish. Right now I have my basic tabs setup using fragments, but that doesn't allow me to have activities running inside my tabs, let alone the option for switching between separate activities all in their own respected tab.

I've been working for a very long time and I just need some guidance, so any help is appreciated. Thank you for your time and if you need any additional information please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Im sure you've read the documentation on [TabActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html). Bottom line is that the Activities you had for each of the tabs should be replaced by Fragments. An activity is now more of a superstructure which can contain multiple fragments each with their own views. The reason behind it is that it makes your application more modular. You could have the fragments as tabs on the phone, but next to eachother on bigger screens etc.

Comment: Ok, this is what I thought, but if each tab is a Fragment, how can I then have fragments within each tab, seeing as a fragment cannot be placed inside a fragment?

Comment: have a view for each tab and put the fragments in there?

Comment: That's probably the way to go. Maybe I should look into views more than I already have. I thought they were just more or less of a container for an activity. But you're saying they can be a container of fragments?

Comment: well, a fragment has a root view, which you can add to your activity its view hierarchy afaik